# Skipping a macro to break links when saving if there are no links

Tags: vba, excel

I have a costing spreadsheet I designed where some of my costing items are linked to other workbooks. I have a macro so when I save a cost sheet it breaks the links so going forward the costs will be locked in and not update. However, if I re-save my spreadsheet it debugs and says there are no links to break. I am trying to figure out a way to bypass this break links macro after the first save once the links have already been broken. The only way I can do it now is to go in and delete this portion of my macro out when I try to save again. Below is my entire save macro, the first part of it is the part that breaks the links. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Sub Save()
'To break links to Ultra-D
ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:="H:\JUNK\Quotes\Al Costing\Ultra-D\Ultra-D.xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks
'To Save
Range("D8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("D7").Select
Dim Proposal As String
Dim Customer As String
Dim System As String


Proposal = Range("D3").Value
Customer = Range("D4").Value
System = Range("D5").Value


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\Users\walkerja\Desktop\Al Quotes\" & Proposal & " " & Customer & " SCR-Al-" & System & " Tsoc.xlsm", FileFormat:= _
xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: In general you would want to use an IF statement with some sort of "flag" that you saved somewhere else. You can store this flag in cell on a hidden sheet.

Comment: Why don't you write something into a cell on a hidden sheet. If it matches a special condition like "firstsave" then decide to execute the break part or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `ActiveWorkBook.BreakLink......` with the following.

If there are any links then there will be data in `LinkCheck(1)` if there is no data then it will be empty.

```
  If Not IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources) Then
      ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:="H:\JUNK\Quotes\Al Costing\Ultra-D\Ultra-D.xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinksEnd
 End if
```

Comment: I appreciate your response Jean-Pierre. The only problem I am having is it debugs on the If Not LinkCheck(1) = Empty Then on the second save. If I remove the (1) it fixes it on the second save but debugs on the first save.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that worked like a charm. I altered it a little bit and posted my final code below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a ton to Jean-Pierre's answer. I just wanted to post my final code below.

```
'To break links
Dim MyLinks As Variant
    MyLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources) Then
    For I = 1 To UBound(MyLinks)
    ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=MyLinks(I), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next I
    End If
```